# running Keras on macOs through the terminal with python installed?

Tags: python

When I type the command, 'from tensorflow import keras' into the terminal on macOS, I get

"from: can't read /var/mail/tensorflow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just write Python code into the CLI directly. That only accepts shell commands to some extent.

You can either:

1. fire up a Python interpreter from your CLI and use that directly, e.g.

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  5 2021, 01:50:46)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow import keras
```

2. or write all of your code into a text file and name it something like `my_first_script.py`, e.g.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# the rest of your code
```

Then you run that with python, e.g.

```sh
$ python my_first_script.py
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) here.